# Render uploading items in outside of the FineUploader wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fine-uploader

When you uploading some file, Fine uploader does something like following image:

[image: 1]
But I want to when user uploading some file, Fine uploader display uploading item like following image:

[image]

I wrote following codes but when upload some file, display file inside the FineUploader wrapper and also in the bottom of that. But I want to display only in the bottom of the uploader

```
const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({
  options: {
    request: {
      endpoint: "http://example.com/upload"
    },
});

componentDidMount() {
    uploader.on('submitted', (id) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            uploadingItems: [...prevState.uploadingItems, id]
        }))
    })
}

<FileInput uploader={ uploader } />
{
    this.state.uploadingItems.length &&
        this.state.uploadingItems.map(id => (
            <div key={ id }>
                <Thumbnail id={ id } uploader={ uploader } />
                <PauseResumeButton id={ id } uploader={ uploader } />
                <progressBar id={id} uploader={uploader} />
            </div>
        ))
}
```